# Integration using Redhat Fuse Karaf 6.3 with OSGi Blueprint

Tags: apache-camel, redhat, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, camel-cxf

We have requirement to integrate our source system with two external systems.
We decided to use below Fuse Environement.
 - jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-187
 - OSGi(blueprint) 
Their external system (REST Service deployed in Redhat JBoss EAP.

We came up with below integration approach :
 i.  Create Apache Camel CXF REST service as OSGi bundle and deploy in Fuse
 ii. Bundle have blueprint xml with i)from-uri(REST url) ii) to- 
     uri(http://external system1) iii) to-uri(http://external system2)
iii. Soure system(REST Client) will call the from-uri and fuse will forward 
     its request to external system

We are not able to finalize if the approach will work in production environment
and can it be configurable if more external system added in future.

Any suggestion or sharing of experience on same approach or any other workable approach would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Camel is very flexible, so you can in the future integrate with more systems. Your questions is a bit too open and not a good fit for SO IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Claus Ibsen for the quick response with valuable information provided. I could  not confirm it, may I request you to elaborate little more, so that we can confirm and go ahead with the this approach. Thanks again

Comment: Why are you using JBoss Fuse 6.3, which is a rather old release. Red Hat Fuse 7.x is the latest release at this moment. If you are an existing Red Hat Fuse customer you can use their customer portal to get help/support with the product. SO is not a good place for your high level question. Sit down and try to build and use the product is IMHO a good way to learn. And there are 1000s of Camel users world-wide in product that use Camel in very different and flexible ways.

Comment: Thanks Claus Ibsen.